# combining the two awk file

Tags: ubuntu, shell, awk

I am trying to detact the selfish node based on the ncr and energy equation.. I have already detacted the selfish node, but based on ncr and energy separately.. and I had a problem combining the two conditions (if the node's ncr is less than 30 and its energy is less than the threshold, it is classified as a node  selfish)

This is the awk code for detecting the selfish node based on energy..

```
BEGIN {
        
        n=38
         SelfishCounter=0;
   Normalcounter=0;
}
{
    # Trace line format: energy
        event = $1
        time = $2
        if (event == "r" || event == "d" || event == "s"|| event == "f") {
        node_id = $3
        energy=$14
        }
        if (event=="N"){
        node_id = $5
        energy=$7
        }
    # Store remaining energy
    finalenergy[node_id]=energy
}
END {
    # finalenergy for each node
    
    for (i in finalenergy) {
       finalenergy[i]
        totalenergy = 0
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 1)  
        totalenergy += finalenergy[i]
    }
    ###compute average energy

    threshold=totalenergy/n
    ####output
    
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        
   if(threshold >finalenergy[i]){

  SelfishCounter++;       }
else if(threshold <finalenergy[i]){
      Normalcounter++;  }
        }
printf "number of selfish nodes:%d \n", SelfishCounter;
        printf "number of normal nodes:%d \n", Normalcounter;
    
       
}
```

This is the awk code for detecting the selfish node based on NCR..I used the sh file with it

```
BEGIN { 
    ReqCounter=0;
    RepCounter=0;
    NCRCounter=0;
    Normalcounter=0;
    max_node = 0;
} 
    
{action=$1; 
 
if(action == "s" || action == "r" || action == "f") 
{ 
 if(($33 == "REQUEST") && ($5==node))
    ReqCounter++;
if(($33 == "REPLY") && ($5==node))
    RepCounter++;
 
} 
}
END { 
    NCR= ((ReqCounter-(ReqCounter-RepCounter))/ReqCounter)*100;
 

    
 if(NCR <= "30"){
    NCRCounter++; 
    printf "SELFISH\n"; }
else{
  Normalcounter++;
  printf "NORMAL\n";}
    

   # printf "The Node number is:%d \n", node;
   # printf "The NCRis:%d \n", NCR;
    #printf "REQUEST Count:%d \n", ReqCounter;
    #printf "REPLY Count:%d \n", RepCounter;
    
    
    
}
```

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0
SelfishNodes=0
NormalNodes=0
while [ $i -lt 38 ]
do
value=$(awk -v node=$i -f NCR.awk DSR.tr)
echo "Node" $i "is" $value
i=`expr $i + 1`
 if [ "$value" = "SELFISH" ]
    then
    SelfishNodes=` expr $SelfishNodes + 1`
 else
    NormalNodes=`expr $NormalNodes + 1`
 fi
 
done
echo "Total Number of Sefiish Nodes are:" $SelfishNodes
echo "Totl Number of Normal Nodes are:"$NormalNodes
```

When I mix the two awk files shown above together

```
BEGIN {
        
   n=38
   SelfishCounter=0;
   Normalcounter=0;
   ReqCounter=0;
   RepCounter=0;

}
{
    # Trace line format: energy
        event = $1
        time = $2
        if (event == "r" || event == "d" || event == "s"|| event == "f") {
        node_id = $3
        energy=$14
       if(($33 == "REQUEST") && ($5 == node))
        ReqCounter++;
        if(($33 == "REPLY") && ($5 == node))
    RepCounter++;
          }
         if (event=="N"){
        node_id = $5
        energy=$7
        }
       
       
    # Store remaining energy
    finalenergy[node_id]=energy
}
END {
   NCR= ((ReqCounter-(ReqCounter-RepCounter))/ReqCounter)*100;
 
    # finalenergy for each node
    
    for (i in finalenergy) {
       finalenergy[i]
        totalenergy = 0
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 1)  
        totalenergy += finalenergy[i]
    }
    ###compute average energy

    threshold=totalenergy/n
    ####output
    
 

 if((threshold >finalenergy[i]) || (NCR <= 30)){
    SelfishCounter++; 
    printf "SELFISH\n"; }
else{
  Normalcounter++;
  printf "NORMAL\n";}
    
}
        }
    
       
}
```

```
#!/bin/sh
i=0
SelfishNodes=0
NormalNodes=0
while [ $i -lt 38 ]
do
value=$(awk -v node=$i -f energy-ncr.awk DSR.tr)
echo "Node" $i "is" $value
i=`expr $i + 1`
 if [ "$value" = "SELFISH" ]
    then
    SelfishNodes=` expr $SelfishNodes + 1`
 else
    NormalNodes=`expr $NormalNodes + 1`
 fi
 
done
echo "Total Number of Sefiish Nodes are:" $SelfishNodes
echo "Totl Number of Normal Nodes are:"$NormalNodes
```

the following error appears

```
Node 33 is
awk: energy-ncr.awk:59:         }
awk: energy-ncr.awk:59:         ^ syntax error
awk: energy-ncr.awk:62: }
awk: energy-ncr.awk:62: ^ syntax error
Node 34 is
awk: energy-ncr.awk:59:         }
awk: energy-ncr.awk:59:         ^ syntax error
awk: energy-ncr.awk:62: }
awk: energy-ncr.awk:62: ^ syntax error
Node 35 is
awk: energy-ncr.awk:59:         }
awk: energy-ncr.awk:59:         ^ syntax error
awk: energy-ncr.awk:62: }
awk: energy-ncr.awk:62: ^ syntax error
Node 36 is
awk: energy-ncr.awk:59:         }
awk: energy-ncr.awk:59:         ^ syntax error
awk: energy-ncr.awk:62: }
awk: energy-ncr.awk:62: ^ syntax error
Node 37 is
Total Number of Sefiish Nodes are: 0
Totl Number of Normal Nodes are:38
```

---

EDIT by Ed Morton: here are the OPs 2 first awk scripts formatted by `gawk -o-` so they have indentation, etc. that make the code much easier to understand:

Script 1:

```
BEGIN {
        n = 38
        SelfishCounter = 0
        Normalcounter = 0
}

{
        # Trace line format: energy
        event = $1
        time = $2
        if (event == "r" || event == "d" || event == "s" || event == "f") {
                node_id = $3
                energy = $14
        }
        if (event == "N") {
                node_id = $5
                energy = $7
        }
        # Store remaining energy
        finalenergy[node_id] = energy
}

END {
        # finalenergy for each node
        for (i in finalenergy) {
                finalenergy[i]
                totalenergy = 0
                for (i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                        totalenergy += finalenergy[i]
                }
        }
        ###compute average energy
        threshold = totalenergy / n
        ####output
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (threshold > finalenergy[i]) {
                        SelfishCounter++
                } else if (threshold < finalenergy[i]) {
                        Normalcounter++
                }
        }
        printf "number of selfish nodes:%d \n", SelfishCounter
        printf "number of normal nodes:%d \n", Normalcounter
}
```

Script 2:

```
BEGIN {
        ReqCounter = 0
        RepCounter = 0
        NCRCounter = 0
        Normalcounter = 0
        max_node = 0
}

{
        action = $1
        if (action == "s" || action == "r" || action == "f") {
                if (($33 == "REQUEST") && ($5 == node)) {
                        ReqCounter++
                }
                if (($33 == "REPLY") && ($5 == node)) {
                        RepCounter++
                }
        }
}

END {
        NCR = ((ReqCounter - (ReqCounter - RepCounter)) / ReqCounter) * 100
        if (NCR <= "30") {
                NCRCounter++
                printf "SELFISH\n"
        } else {
                Normalcounter++
                printf "NORMAL\n"
        }
        # printf "The Node number is:%d \n", node;
        # printf "The NCRis:%d \n", NCR;
        #printf "REQUEST Count:%d \n", ReqCounter;
        #printf "REPLY Count:%d \n", RepCounter;
}
```

Comment: Looks like extra closing braces on line 57 and 60

Comment: whenever you find yourself running the same awk script with the same input file in a shell loop, you should rewrite it so that the loop is done inside the awk script.  given that you're iterating the loop 38 times, from 0 to 37, doing the loop in awk will be *at least* 38 times faster (and probably much more due to the overhead for repeatedly starting up awk).  It looks like your awk code is already storing the energy for each id into an array, so that only needs to be read once.   e.g. the END block could have a for loop like `for `node=0;node < 38; node++) {...}`

Comment: If you fix your indenting it'll make your whole script much clearer and, among other things, make it very obvious if your opening and closing braces don't line up. I ran both of your awk scripts through `gawk -o-` to make them readable. Obviously I can't do that with the 3rd one as it contains syntax errors so gawk can't parse it but if you format it yourself following the example I provided for the first 2 then you'll see the issue. Also copy/paste your shell script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the issues it tells you about then update your question with the fixed version of that.

Comment: also in the END block of awk scripts 1 & 3, you're using `i` as the iterator variable for both loops in a nested loop.  `for (i in finalenergy) { ... ; for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)  ... }`.   The statements in the loop don't even seem to make sense.   why not just `for (i in finalenergy) { totalenergy += finalenergy[i] }`?  Also, awk variables are initialised to zero, so there's no need to explictly set them to 0.   and is `n` a count of the nodes in the `finalenergy` array? if so, there's no need to hard-code it to 38 - use `n=length(finalenergy)`.

Comment: So, it looks like the BEGIN block isn't needed. You're also doing a lot of stuff in the END block that should be done in the main loop (e.g. the `for (i in finalenergy) { totalenergy += finalenergy[i]` loop in END can be replaced with just `totalenergy += energy` in the main loop.

Comment: The expression `finalenergy[i]` in the `for (i in finalenergy)` does nothing. Outside of such a loop, it would ensure that a `finalenergy` array exists which has `i` as a key, but that is moot; of course `i` is a key since it's the key iterator.